# Lightswitch HTML custom control show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I've a LS project with one Custom Control where I render a chart with chartjs. The first time I load the page everything is ok, but if I move to another page and then come back the custom control is not rendered anymore (the code is called but nothing appear). I have to press F5 everytime I want to see it!

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: 
I've notice that if I set a global variable, when I come back to the screen the variable is not reinizialized .Also another page containing the jquery-week calendar has the same issue. When I navigate away from a screen and later come back I load another instance of the "screen" or only get the old one, with all the stuff already loaded?

here the code

```
/// <reference path="~/GeneratedArtifacts/viewModel.js" />

function updateGraphs(chart, query, inizio, fine) {
    var last = 0;
    for (var i = inizio; i <= fine; i.addDays(1)) {
        query(i).execute().then(function (res) {
            try {
                if (chart.datasets[0].points.length > 25)
                    chart.removeData();
                var date = new Date(inizio.valueOf()).addDays(last++);
                var str = format_2digit(date.getDate()) + "/" + format_2digit(date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                chart.addData([res.results.length], last % 5 == 0 ? str : "");
            }
            catch (e) { alert(e); }
        });
    }
}

myapp.Home.created = function (screen) {
    var now = new Date();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var year = now.getFullYear();

    screen.GraficoInizio = new Date(year, month, 1);
    screen.GraficoFine = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
};

myapp.Home.GraficoFine_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoInizio", function (value) {
        var month = contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio.getMonth();
        var year = contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio.getFullYear();
        contentItem.value = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
    });
};

myapp.Home.GraficoClienti_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    // creo il grafico

    $(element).append("<canvas id='chartClienti' width='500px' height='300px' />");
    var ctx = $('#chartClienti').get(0).getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx);

    var data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: [],
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: []
            }
        ]
    };

    chart = chart.Line(data, { animationSteps: 15 });
    contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoInizio", function (value) {
        updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi,contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
    });
    contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoFine", function (value) {
        updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi, contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
    });
};

myapp.Home.StampaQRCode_execute = function (screen) {
    var popup = window.open("../QRCode.aspx");
    popup.focus();
};
```

Comment: please show your code to us.

Comment: the screen only have two DateTime selector and the Custom Control. The Chart show how many "subscribe" are active during the timespan between the two date. (Is a Gym Management System example, for University)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var globalVariableForchartClienti;

myapp.Home.GraficoClienti_render = function (element, contentItem) {
// creo il grafico

var chartClientiElementId = 'chartClienti_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999999) + 1);    
$(element).append("<canvas id='" + chartClientiElementId + "' width='500px' height='300px' />");

//You can use "globalVariableForchartClienti" to access custom element in any other function
globalVariableForchartClienti = chartClientiElementId;

var ctx = $('#chartClienti').get(0).getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx);

var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: [],
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
        }
    ]
};

chart = chart.Line(data, { animationSteps: 15 });
contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoInizio", function (value) {
    updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi,contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
});
contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoFine", function (value) {
    updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi, contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
});
```

};

Comment: This solution is better as it does not interfering "Back Button" logic

Comment: Thanks , it worked . Sorry for the delayed response , but SO did not send a notification to me...

Answer (score 1):

Lightswitch does not remove (it hides) html elements from page when you navigate to another page. -> That's how the "Back Button" Works, it shows/set visible the "old page".

When you navigate back to the page in page source you will be able to find more than one "chartClienti" element.

One possible solution is to remove the element if it already exists:

myapp.Home.GraficoClienti_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    // creo il grafico

```
var existedChart = $('#chartClienti');
//element exists if it's length is more than 0
if (existedChart.length > 0) { 
    existedChart.remove();
}

$(element).append("<canvas id='chartClienti' width='500px' height='300px' />");
var ctx = $('#chartClienti').get(0).getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx);

var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: [],
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: []
        }
    ]
};

chart = chart.Line(data, { animationSteps: 15 });
contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoInizio", function (value) {
    updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi,contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
});
contentItem.dataBind("screen.GraficoFine", function (value) {
    updateGraphs(chart, myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.AbbonamentiAttivi, contentItem.screen.GraficoInizio, contentItem.screen.GraficoFine);
});
```

};

Better solution would be following:
A) getting the all elements with that id and updating the latest.
B) give unique id each time you render your control (autoincrement by one: chartClienti0, chartClienti1, ... chartClientiN)